# Kusto Query Language: Get keyword that was matched (has_any)

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am feeding a csv file in my KQL as an external data source. I run a query to match a column:

```
Events | where Title has_any (ColumnName) | project Title, EventId
```

Now, I want to join the output with the column value that was matched. Like if column has values:
"test","test2","test3" and "test2" was matched in the above query, result table should be something like:

```
Title,EventId,MatchedColumnValue
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it using the [has_any_index()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/has-any-index-function) function:

```
let Values = dynamic(["title1", "title2", "title3"]);
let Events = datatable(EventId:int, Title:string)[1,"this is title2, and its boring", 2, "title3 is great", 3, "Nothing to find"];
Events
| extend Idx = has_any_index(Title, Values)
| extend MatchedTitle = iif(Idx<0, "", tostring(Values[Idx]))
| project-away Idx
```

Comment: You are using index of Values array. The length is unknown or too long to type. So, how can we do it without explicitly mentioning the indexes

Comment: thanks for the persistence Dhruv, I found a "hidden" function that does exactly what you are looking for. I updated my answer